# Need help with algebra in a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So the differential equation is this:
$y'=(xy'+y)y^3$

Im trying to get this into standard form for an exact differential equation:
$M(x,y)dx + N(x,y)dy=0$

I found via an online calculator that the standard form is
$-y+\cfrac{1-xy^3}{y^3}y'=0$

But I have no idea how they calculated this. Can anyone help me understand the algebra  used?

Comment: try $(xi)'=\dfrac {y'}{y^3}$ and integrate

Comment: Sorry it's a typo $(xy)'=y'/y^3$

Answer (score 1):

$$y'-(xy'+y)y^3=0$$
$$dy-(xy'+y)y^3dx=0$$
$$\dfrac 1 {y^3}dy-ydx-xdy=0$$
$$\dfrac {dy}{y^3}-d(xy)=0$$
It's exact $(u=xy,v=y)$:
$$\dfrac {dv}{v^3}-du=0$$
It's on the form
$$f(u,v)dv+g(u,v)du=0$$
With
$$\partial_u f=\partial_v g=0$$

You can integrate.

Comment: wouldn't ∂vf be -3/v^-4? and not 0?

Comment: I corrected the line and it gives zero check it again @SleeperMan23

Answer (score 0):

The ODE can be written as
$$y^{-3} dy= d(xy) \implies \int\frac{dy}{y^3}= \int d(xy) \implies \frac{y^{-2}}{-2}=xy+C$$

Comment: This matches the solution on the online calculator. Do I actually not even have to use an exact DE methodology to solve this problem? I just thought I did.

Comment: Let the OP decide, cheers !